# How do I set a page as the default wiki page on Google Code?

Tags: wiki, google-code

I have several wiki pages on my project hosted on Google Code. How do I set one of my pages as a "Table of Contents"? I noticed that for some other projects, naming a page as TableOfContents will make it the default page displayed on clicking the "Wiki" tab. This did not work for me.

How do I add a "Table of Contents" to my Google Code wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

Under the "Administer" tab, select "Tabs". Enter the name of the "Table of Contents" page in the "Wiki:" textbox.

**Bonus tip:** To set a project-wide sidebar (almost always a TOC, displayed on all wiki pages):

- Select the "Administer" tab, click on "Wiki"
- Scroll down to the "Wiki sidebar" section
- Enter the name of the sidebar page under "Show the following page as a sidebar on all wiki pages:"